# Countdown doesn't reset for next year

Tags: javascript

We had this countdown for Christmas, but now it shows expired instead of resetting to next year

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 24, " + year + " 23:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="clock"
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + "hrs. " + minutes + "mins. " + seconds + "secs. ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

The 'expired' message should maybe show during the 25-26th of December and then reset back to counting on 27th till next year?

Comment: It'll "reset" in January, surely?

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Do you understand the code you've posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cant see where you check if your date is later than december, 26th, here should be code like this

```
if (days < -2) {
  countDownDate = new Date("Dec 24, " + (year + 1) + " 23:00:00").getTime();
} else if (distance < 0) {
  clearInterval(x);
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
```

or better just in the very beginning write

```
var now = new Date()
var year = now.getFullYear() + (now.getMonth() == 11 && now.getDate() > 26)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are suggested edits to your code. Near the top, we decide which year's Christmas to count down to.

If you look over the code and commments, you can see more about how date information can be used in JavaScript.

If you want to know more, there's great information at [MDN's Date Object page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
// Get a Date object for the current time before starting the countdown
let startTime = new Date()

// Get the year, month and day from the date object
let year = startTime.getFullYear();
let monthIndex = startTime.getMonth();
let dayOfMonth = startTime.getDate();
//console.log (`${year} ${monthIndex} ${dayOfMonth}`);
if (monthIndex === 11 && dayOfMonth > 27){ // Jan has monthIndex == 0
  year = year + 1; // Use next year
}

// Set the date we're counting down to
let countDownDate = new Date("Dec 24, " + year + " 23:00:00").getTime();

// Start the countdown, updating the display every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get a Date object for the current second of the countdown
  var date = new Date()

  // Get the timestamp from the Date object
  var now = date.getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Function to show "day" if 1 day, "days" if 2 or more days, etc.
  function pluralIfAppropriate(value, singularLabel, pluralLabel){
    if(value == 1){
      return singularLabel;
    }
    else{
      if(pluralLabel == undefined){
        pluralLabel = singularLabel + "s";
      }
      return pluralLabel;
    }
  }
  
  // Builds the display text
  let displayText = `${days} ${pluralIfAppropriate(days, "day")} ${hours}${pluralIfAppropriate(hours, "hr")} ${minutes}${pluralIfAppropriate(minutes, "min")} ${seconds}${pluralIfAppropriate(seconds, "sec")}`;
  
  // Displays the displayText in the element with id="clock"
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = displayText;
 
  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
```